# Why Does a Vector of Class Objects Delete the Objects When Adding Objects with push_back

Tags: c++, vector

When I ask why the vector deletes the objects I'm not referring to the mechanics of what a vector does when it's capacity is exceeded by adding elements to it. I know that once a vector reaches capacity the memory that was originally allocated is deleted and then new larger memory is allocated to accommodate the increased number of elements. For a vector of class objects that means the destructors will be called.

What I am wondering is why exactly when I try to access the members of my class I get the error "error reading characters of string" after exceeding the capacity of my class object vector with push_back().

I tried changing push_back to emplace_back() but that didn't help. I got it to work by declaring a vector of a specific size and using at() to assign values but at that point why am I even using a vector to begin with?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <utility>
#include "Book.h"
using namespace std;

int main () {
    string holder[5]; //used to hold strings from file.
    int temp; //Used to hold number from file.
    ifstream infile;

    vector<pair<Book, int>> bookInfo;

    infile.open(bookDatabase.txt)
    //i < 8 because the vector needs to start off holding 8 book objects.
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        //Second for loop designed based on specific format of the file.
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) 
            getline(infile, holder[j]);
        infile >> temp;
        infile.ignore() //ignore newline;

        //Call class constructor for 5 string inputs.
        Book tempBook(holder[0], holder[1], holder[2], holder[3], holder[4]);

        //Here is where, in the debugger, I see that the string members of my 
        //book class all read "error reading characters of string"
        bookInfo.push_back(make_pair(tempBook, temp));

        //Read in empty line that separates information from book to book. 
        string tempString;
        getline(infile, tempString);
    }
    infile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

My Book object has only string members and basic getter and setter functions as well as a function that prints the book's basic information. It has no pointer members and works perfectly.

I'm also certain that the creation of the pairs and the file input is being done correctly.

What I'm wondering is why I lose my book objects when I exceed vector capacity. I'm allowed to create a vector of class objects so why isn't there a mechanism to preserve the contents of the objects whenever the vector needs to move into bigger memory when capacity is exceeded? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can [edit] your question to include the "book.h" header (and "book.cpp" file) so we can see what the copy constructor and assignment operator etc. are dong?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a debugger problem? What happens if you make the program print the strings out again - does it work okay?

Comment: When a vector reallocates it copies or moves all of the objects to the new memory. Without seeing your Book class it's hard to tell, but I'd bet you're not following the rule of 3/5/0.

Comment: I didn’t write a copy constructor or a copy assignment operator. I actually thought it might be because I needed to write those for my book class but shouldn’t the default copy constructor work fine since book has no dynamic variables?

Comment: @immibis It’s not the debugger. Everywhere else in the program at large that needs access to Book’s members doesn’t work properly.

Comment: It's impossible to know given the code shown here unless you show everything.. Why? Because if we assume that Book only holds "std::string".. then the default copy constructor will copy it just fine when the vector resizes.. If it does NOT and it holds pointers to something, then that might explain it.. We simply cannot give an answer without more code.

Comment: @Brandon I mention in the OP that Book has no pointers.

Comment: You should post the code instead of describing it

Comment: @ath3sius -- By not showing us what `Book` is, you're going to have someone  show you there is nothing wrong with `vector` by writing a simple `Book` class, disputing all of the claims you're making.  So you can either show your class and have it explained to you what is happening, or have someone show you that you're mistaken by writing their own simple `Book` class.

Comment: @ath3sius -- Well, [this doesn't show any issue](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95bdaacc16a58432).  All the `Book` information remains in the vector.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and I'm gonna post my findings for posterity's sake. I apologize to the wonderful souls that were trying to help me for not posting the code to the book class but I just now got to a position where I could post code.

I'm not sure what was causing my program to mess up elsewhere but my vector issue was just me being confused. The debugger acted odd from my point of view so I assumed something was wrong but the "error reading characters from string" was from the old memory that was deleted. The members were successfully copied to a __that object (not sure if object is right) and after tackling it again my vectors worked precisely as they were supposed to.